# Just installed new gfx card and no picture - but no BIOS beeps either

Tags: video, graphics-card, pci-express

I have a [Gigabyte M61P-S3 Motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2434#sp) and my gfx card died. I kept using the machine for about 2 weeks - because I could axs videos and such from my PS3. So that's what I did.

But my monitor never worked - there were lots of colors and pixels on the screen, nothing of sense. i.e. a lot of colorful, visual noise.

So today I just put in this [XFX Video Card](http://www.xpcgear.com/xfx-on-xfx1-pls2.html) and when I turn on the computer I hear no beeps, but I see no picture on my monitor.

First I tried the monitor in the VGA port, then I tried DVI and nothing.

**Edit 1**: I don't ever see a picture - not even a BIOS screen or a the pre-OS stuff. Nothing at all. The monitor just looks like it is about to turn on, and then goes into 'power saving mode'.

**Edit 2**: So I took out the video card, and plugged the VGA cord of my monitor into the on-board gfx port and reset the CMOS. Still no video to my monitor. The issue is that I think my on-board gfx port died about 2 years ago. Not 100% sure, but I think so.

**Edit 3**: So I tried putting in my old video card, and I get a signal to my monitor - but the monitor looks like this [image: static-on-monitor-from-old-gfx-card]. So I am not sure why it won't POST with the new gfx card. Also, I believe that if I let it...the computer will boot to Windows. I can then blindly type in my password and my computer will boot to Windows, and I can axs files via the network. I just can't see anything on the monitor.

**Edit 4**: I plugged out all peripherals, from the back of the computer, except for the monitor and power cable....for what that's worth. I have a few other things in my PCI slots and such as usual. None of that has changed or given me any problems.

**Edit 5**: So, I checked my case and I don't see an internal speaker - so that's prolly why I am hearing no beeps. But what else can I do to get this working.

The thing is, I know it sounds like my mobo may be fried - but why would I be able to use it with my other video card for 2 weeks without getting monitor, if the mobo is fried? I am stumped!

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's your PSU? Does it provide enough power for the GPU? What model of GPU is it?

Comment: It's a 500W PSU. It does provide enough power. I fixed it.

Comment: That looks exactly like what happens when you forget to plug the power-cable into the video-card.

Comment: Yeh....except that this video card doesn't have a slot for the PSU cable. Looked on my old one too and it didn't have it either :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it.

I took out the new GFX card and re-seated it.

It seems that the POST process before the BIOS screen takes longer than normal. Maybe as a result of the new GFX card, but now it is working.

It may have had something to do with my resetting the CMOS that fixed it, I think.

Not too sure, but I tried a bunch of stuff.

Now I am downloading the new drivers and everything seems to be going 'according to plan'.

Comment: Sometimes the default in the BIOS setup is to run a test on all RAM on POST, if you have a lot of memory then it takes a long time to run - you can usually skip this more thorough check by selecting "quick POST" or something similar.